# Ask for input until exact string is input problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my Python code:

```
choice = (input("Are you signed up? (y/n) "))

print(choice)

while True:
    if choice != "y" or choice != "n":
        choice = (input("Are you signed up? (y/n) "))
        print(choice)
    else:
        break
```

I want the program to keep asking the user for input until they input "y" or "n". The problem is it never accepts the input, even if they do input "y" or "n".

When I print what they inputted (that's a real word) it says that it's "y" or "n" but it still won't accept it.

I've been using Python for some time now and I'm just trying something out today but I can't figure this out for some reason, I feel like it's something simple and obvious but I'm stupid to notice it.

Can someone explain this to me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `or` use `and`. Right now the `if` statement always matches. If the user inputs “y”, `choice != "n"` is still true.

Comment: Don’t use unnecessary parentheses around your `input` call. They’re inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It was `str(input(...))` but I removed `str` and forgot to remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You need `and` instead of `or` in this case.

```
    if choice != "y" and choice != "n":
```

or if you prefer you can do

```
    if not (choice == "y" or choice == "n"):
```

You can also do:

```
    if choice not in ("y", "n"):    # THIS ONE IS PROBABLY THE BEST
```

or because these are each 1-character you can do:

```
    if choice not in "yn":
```

You can also do:

```
    if choice not in "Randy!" or choice in "Rad!":
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `choice` cannot be `'y'` and `'n'` at the same time, one of `choice != 'y'` and `choice != 'n'` is always true.

You need to use `and`, not `or`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it kind of doesn't make sense to me why it would be `and`.

Example:
"Keep hitting this until it turns red OR until it turns purple.", meaning you should stop hitting it once one of those is satisfied.

"Keep hitting this until it turns red AND until it turns purple.", meaning you should stop hitting it once it's both red and purple.

Comment: @itzn4utiluss It’s more like "keep hitting this *while* it hasn’t turned red *and* hasn’t turned purple either."

Answer (score 1):

Well, suppose the user inputs `"y"`.

1. Your code will enter the `while True` loop and encounter the `if` condition
2. Is `choice != "y" or choice != "n"`, where `choice == 'y'`, true or false?

   1. `"y" != "y"` is false, check the next condition
   2. `"y" != "n"` is true, so the whole condition is true
3. Ask for input again
4. Goto (1)

Same thing happens for `choice == "n"`.

---

However, you want a condition that says `not (choice == "y" or choice == "n")`. According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
not (a or b) == (not a) and (not b)
```

So your code translates into:

```
(not (choice == "y")) and (not (choice == "n"))
=> choice != "y" and choice != "n"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has already pointed out the problem in your code, I am just adding a cleaned version of your code.

```
while True:
    choice = (input("Are you signed up? (y/n) "))

    if choice == "y" or choice == "n":
        print(f"Your choice is {choice}")
        break
```